# Why is User Location not MKUserLocation?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

There's one annotation only - the user location. I did not add any other one.

Here's my code:

```
public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
{
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
    {
        return null;//never hit
    }
    else if (annotation is myAnnotation  a)
    {
        return a.View;//never hit of course.
    }
    else
    {
        string vvvvvvv = annotation.GetType().ToString();//"MKAnnotationWrapper"
        return null;//hit even though I didn't add anything else.
    }
}
```

Why is the user location appearing as an `MKAnnotationWrapper` and not as an `MKUserLocation`?

Comment: Read this [comment](https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/26/26416/bug.html#c1) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have reference to OBJC runtime object and then you can check it for example :

```
    [Export("mapView:viewForAnnotation:")]
    public MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        //pass pointer to GetNSObject and cast it to MKUserLocation then you
        //can know if it is user location or not
        var userAnnotation = Runtime.GetNSObject(annotation.Handle) as MKUserLocation;
        if (userAnnotation != null)
        {
            return null;//when returning null there will be default pin for user
        }
        var annView = new MKAnnotationView//custom annotation logic
           {
               Image = pinImage,
               CanShowCallout = false,
               Annotation = annotation,
            };
        return annView;
    }
```